# facebook php canvas app oauth dialog page error

Tags: php, facebook, cakephp, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-canvas

I am trying to create a facebook canvas app. I am using facebook php-sdk and cakephp.

This is my login function:-

```
public function login() {

       $app_id = "xxxxxxxxxxx";
       $app_secret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
       $canvas_page = "https://apps.facebook.com/xxxxxxx";
       $scope = 'email,publish_actions';
       $facebook = new Facebook(array(
                                'appId'  => $app_id,
                                'secret' => $app_secret
                                ));

       $user = $facebook->getUser();

       if ($user) {

                try {

                // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
                $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
                $access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
                $fbid = $user_profile['id'];
                pr($user_profile);

                } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {

                error_log($e);
                $user = null;

                }

        } else {

                $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
                                                   'scope' => $scope,
                                                   'redirect_uri' => $canvas_page
                                                   ));
                print('<script> top.location.href=\'' . $loginUrl . '\'</script>');
        }

}
```

This seems to work if the user is already authenticated. But for new user, instead of showing the oauth dialog, it throws this error:-

```
"Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains."
```

I am testing it on localhost. so my canvas url is `http://localhost/xxxxx/`
    Can someone help me out here ?

Comment: Facebook can not detect your localhost, it must be a domain name.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty does that mean I can't develop facebook app on localhost? I also tried using a virtual host but that also does not work. I also hosted the site on aws and replaced "localhost" with <ip address>.. still no luck

Comment: Thats correct, usually you may need a development server to kick off the project. For example I have an API and I get a request with a redirect_uri as  http://localhost/xxx , My code can not do a redirect since the redirect will happen to my local host not yours, But if I know a domain name I can redirect to a domain.

Comment: Well, I am getting what you are trying to say, but if that was the case, then the app should not have worked even when I was not using authentication.
If I put url canvas url as localhost/yyyy which is just a simple html page, it works, but as soon as put authentication code, it ceases to work.

Comment: Not sure about the app but for login the redirect_uri must be domain name and the same should be in your app settings.

Comment: if redirect_uri is set to domain name, then after login instead of going to canvas app it will go to the website...
As mentioned in docs, redirect_uri should be "apps.facebook.com/xxxx"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution:-

Two steps:-

a) Changed redirect_uri to `http://localhost/xxxxxx`

b) Added a check to see if get params has code and set header to canvas page.

Correct Code:-

public function login() {

```
   $app_id = "xxxxxxxxxxx";
   $app_secret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
   $canvas_page = "https://apps.facebook.com/xxxxxxx";
   $scope = 'email,publish_actions';
   $facebook = new Facebook(array(
                            'appId'  => $app_id,
                            'secret' => $app_secret
                            ));
   if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
      header("Location: " . $canvas_page);
      exit;
   }

   $user = $facebook->getUser();

   if ($user) {

            try {

            // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
            $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
            $access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
            $fbid = $user_profile['id'];
            pr($user_profile);

            } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {

            error_log($e);
            $user = null;

            }

    } else {

            $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
                                               'scope' => $scope,
                                               ));
            print('<script> top.location.href=\'' . $loginUrl . '\'</script>');
    }
```

}